# how to define a regex parameter in angular-ui-router to pick only from a set of defined strings

Tags: angularjs

I want my angular-ui-router in a specific state to be able to enter only if the parameter is one of the following strings:

"site1"
"site2"
"site3"

This is my state:

```
$stateProvider.state("error", {
    url: '/error/{sub: (site1 | site2 | site3)}',
    templateUrl: 'views/error.html',
    controller: 'ErrorCtrl'
});
```

But for some reason this doesn't work.
How would i go and define this regex properlly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

According to the documentation of angular-ui-router:

> Don't put capturing parentheses into your regex patterns, the
>   UrlMatcher in ui-router adds those itself around the entire regex.
>   You're effectively introducing a second capture group for the same
>   parameter, which trips up the numbering in the child URL. You can use
>   non-capturing groups though, i.e. (?:...) is fine.

So the solution is just to take them down.

I also had to remove all whitespaces since they actually account for letters.

```
$stateProvider.state("error", {
    url: '/error/{sub:site1|site2|site3}',
    templateUrl: 'views/error.html',
    controller: 'ErrorCtrl'
});
```